# How can I trigger a native Javascript event from a QUnit test?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, qunit

I'm working on a Javascript library that does not depend on jQuery, though I have jQuery and QUnit available in my tests. In the library, I attach an event to an element the way jQuery does:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
  tab.addEventListener('click', MyModule.show, false);
} else if (document.attachEvent) {
  tab.attachEvent('click', MyModule.show);
}
```

I tried calling `$('#tab').click();` in my QUnit test, but it doesn't cause my event handler to be called.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

jQuery has its own event registration system, which is separate from the DOM's event registration. When we call `$(something).click()`, all registered jQuery handlers and the registered `onclick` handler will fire, but nothing else would. For example,

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function() { alert('event') }, false);
document.body.onclick = function() { alert('onclick'); };      

$('body').click(); // alerts "onclick"
```

If you call `document.body.onclick()`, then only the second event will fire and alert "onclick". To get both events to fire, create an event object and dispatch it for the element in question - body in this case. You can find an example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent). Unsurprisingly, IE uses a different mechanism to do the same and you need to call [fireEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536423(VS.85).aspx).

Here's a non cross-browser example for modern browsers (taken from the MDC article above),

```
var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);

document.body.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

Comment: That's... heinous, but I'm certainly not one to blame the messenger :)

Answer (score 1):

(not sure) jQuery uses it's own event system on top of the native event system. `$(el).click()` is invoked directly on that event system and not on the native system. (/not sure)

```
document.getElementById('tab').onclick();
```

Is the native equivalent, but you might want to check first if querying for the element actually *finds* the element. Are you initializing the QUnit tests when the dom is ready?

Also, for attachEvent (IE) you need to prefix events with 'on'.

```
tab.attachEvent('onclick', listenerFn);
```

ps. actually I think that the missing prefix 'on' for the IE equivalent was the problem. Change it and test $().click() again.

Comment: I was running the test in Chrome, so I doubt the IE-specific version was the problem.