# Trigger standard "change" event on form object - to be picked up by any listeners on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a noConflict instance of jQuery that gets automatically included on some of my pages.  This code will automatically update any matching form fields it finds. Eg:

```
var jq = $.noConflict(true);

if (jq('input[name="field_name"]').length > 0) 
{
    jq('input[name="field_name"]').val('field_value');
}
```

I want this code to then trigger that standard in-built "change" event on that form object, so that any listeners/event handlers attached to it will be fired.  Is this possible?

I know you can trigger change events in jquery, but these will only be picked up by the event handlers in the same instance.  Eg:

```
jq('input[name="field_name"]').trigger('change');
```

I want to be able to trigger the change event for **anything** that may be listening for it, be it another instance of jQuery, or standard javascript.

Can anyone help or am I reaching too far?

Thanks

Comment: Try `$.event.trigger('change')`

Comment: I don't necessarily know that a standard instance of jquery will be included on the page, so that code may not always work.

Comment: What do you mean? Also, try `jq('*').trigger('change')` instead

Comment: My code gets automatically added to a page, I don't know anything about the page it is being added to.  I am using noConflict in case the page is already using jquery, but it's equally likely that it won't be. I want my code to trigger a change event that can be picked up by other instances of jquery (if they exist) or any other listeners that may be applied to the form element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger events manually. jQuery actually triggers native events as well, but it appears that jquery doesn't trigger other handlers that were registered with addEventListener though as the fiddler example shows. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3631714/174469 for info about native events)

Here is a fiddler that shows an example: http://jsfiddle.net/EXw4P/2/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="foobar" />
```

Javascript:

```
// Register a non-jquery handler on the textbox
foobar.onchange = function () {
    alert("explicit native onchange");   
}
foobar.addEventListener('change', function() { alert('event listener onchange') }, false);

$("#foobar").change(function () {
    alert("jquery onchange"); 
});

alert("Trigger change from jquery")
$("#foobar").trigger("change");

alert("Trigger native change event")
var fakedEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
fakedEvent.initMouseEvent('change', true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
foobar.dispatchEvent(fakedEvent);
```

Comment: That's perfect thanks!  I've had to use it with getElementsByName (looking into using that with getElementsByTagName as well to be absolutely sure) but so far it seems to be working perfectly. My other solution was to check if jquery was being included normally and if so fire the change event through that, but I'm not comfortable it would cover everything.