# implementing $(el).trigger('my-event', {some: 'data'}); in native js

Tags: javascript, jquery

i will appreciate an assistance on how to implement $(el).trigger('my-event', {some: 'data'}); in native js(without using jquery).
I was able to implement the binder without jquery.

```
        if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener(event, func, false);
        }
        else if (window.attachEvent) {
           window.attachEvent(event, func);
        }
```

I forgot to mention, it need to be supported in IE8
To be more specific. i need custom trigger of 'my-event' and not native trigger such as 'click'

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that it need to support IE8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I trigger a native Javascript event from a QUnit test?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631453/how-can-i-trigger-a-native-javascript-event-from-a-qunit-test)

Comment: no is different.  i need custom trigger of 'my-event' and not native trigger such as 'click'

Comment: What about [EventEmitter](https://github.com/Olical/EventEmitter)?

Comment: thanks @moonwave99 . it actually works !

Comment: Cool, I'll add it as an answer then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [EventEmitter](https://github.com/Olical/EventEmitter):

```
var ee = new EventEmitter();

// Add a listener
ee.addListener('myCustomEvent', function(){
  console.log(arguments) // yay!
});

// Emit custom event
ee.emitEvent('myCustomEvent', ['some', 'arguments'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that when trying to convert from jQuery to Vanilla Javascript this site very helpful: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

```
$(el).trigger('change');
```

is the same as

```
 if (document.createEvent) {
      var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
      event.initEvent('change', true, false);
      el.dispatchEvent(event);
    } else {
      el.fireEvent('onchange');
    }
```

Comment: As you can see in http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ this is for native trigger. in my case i need to trigger 'my-event'. the same site doesn't provide an implementation for it.